# City car parking dataset in EU (and US)

Tags: data-request, uses-of-open-data, city, europe, parking

I want to do a research project about the prediction of car parking occupancy rates and compare different cities in the EU/US.

Are there public datasets that you can recommend?

I found a couple of RSS-feeds which provide real time information via XML, however, I am especially interested in regularly updated historical data for my project.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and describe what logical type of data you need.